# Disable a transition while an animation is running

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Demo of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/t0qsek8n/1/

```html
<div class="test" id="test">Test text</div>
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation: test 5s;
  transition: top 1s;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: none;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
  }
}
```

```
const test = document.getElementById('test');
setTimeout(() => {
    test.style.top = "100px"
}, 1000);
```

I expect if the value of `top` property is changed by JS, transition `transition: top 1000ms` doesn't happen because of `transition: none` that provides `@keyframes test`, but actually, the transition happens.
I cannot understand why `transition` value from `keyframes` doesn't override any existing definition for `transition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's take another example using `display`:

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation: test 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test">
  Test text
</div>
```

We logically expect to never see the element since we set `display:none` and we made the animation to be `forwards` but display is simply ignored because **it cannot be animated**. Same logic with `transition` since it's a property that we cannot animate <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property)</sup>.

Basically, any property that cannot be animated will simply get ignored when used with keyframes.

> Properties that aren't specified in every keyframe are interpolated if possible — properties that can't be interpolated are **dropped from the animation**. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#When_properties_are_left_out_of_some_keyframes)</sup>